# Application of Lebesgue density theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E$ be a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Define $D_E(x) = $$\lim_{r\to0} \frac{m(E\cap B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}$, whenever the limit exists, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure

The questions asks you to prove that $D_E(x)=1$ for $a.e$ $x\in E$ and $D_E(x)=0$ for almost all $x\in E^c$

I believe I have to invoke the Lebesgue density theorem but can't think of how to begin. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploit Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem to the locally integrable function $\chi_{E}$:

\begin{align*}
\chi_{E}(x)=\dfrac{1}{m(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)}\chi_{E}(y)dy,~~~~\text{a.e.}~x.
\end{align*}

Comment: That helps. Thanks a lot. It turns out that this is a straight forward application of LDT.

Comment: I know this is old but shouldn't there be a limit as $r\to 0$ in there?

Comment: Yes, just missed it. You may edit my answer, thank you.